# non-gmo / gmo-free corn cob bedding for parrots & other animals? (in the US)

Tags: safety, parrots, bedding

Hello dear animal friends!

Every time I sign up for auto-ship corn cob through chewy.com I get less than a year before that particular brand/product is slashed from their catalog! Anyway, I started a journey today to try to find something non-gmo because a fellow asked in the Q&A section of one of the products still available. I am passionate about the unadulterated safe non-carcinogenic products we surround ourselves with, as it's not just the animal friend or the human friend, or the children or grandparents, it's the whole world we're poisoning!

So... I found only one company, eurocob, but... well, they seem like they're in Europe, and couldn't find a distributor here in California, US/A. So, the question:

What are some of the safest/lowest dust/non-chemically/non-gmo alternatives to corn cob?

Even better, anyone know any actually pure and natural non-gmo corn cob ? Apparently, since it's not for human consumption, these companies can call gmo corn cob "100%/All Natural"...

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Welcome to Pets. Please keep in mind that this is an international community, so when you write that you "couldn't find a distributor here" you need to clarify where "here" actually is... If you happen to be in the USA you might have to resort to products from Europe, simply because marketing laws are drastically stricter there and you can't always be sure what exactly you get when ordering an American product.

Comment: Thx Elmy, (updated question a while ago). I did find a nice European product, but again, couldn't seem to get it in the US and international shipping I believe was egregious or I couldn't find it in stock anywhere... can't remember... thanks for all you do!